# Hybrid Framework - How to trigger protractor test js from another test js file?

Tags: json, selenium, protractor

I'm not sure if anyone has attempted this on Protractor. Basically the following is my goal:

1. Read test data from csv. This is done and completed using csvtojson plugin. The plugin converts my csv data to json and the protractor test reads the json data.
2. Protractor.conf.js should remain untouched. I found listing all test on the Protractor.conf.js spec section is messy. The spec section should call only MasterTest.js file that reads from masterData.json who later dictate what test to call and run on which environment, which browser etc.
3. MasterTest.js should call the individual test js file and run the test. This is the part i'm stuck with and don't know how to trigger the test?

Currently I have a login.js test which reads data from loginData.json.

On my protractor.conf.js I entered `specs: './SystemTestSuites/MasterTest.js'`

On MasterTest.js

```
describe('MasterTest', function() {
var masterData = require('../TestData/json/masterData.json');

masterData.forEach(function (data)
if (data.testCase === 'login') {
    //I don't know how to call login.js
});

});
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: `require 'login.js'` does not work for you ?

Comment: @Dziamid Thanks! it works. I did require('./login.js'); However do you know how to pass a parameter to the require suppose if you need to run login.js on different environment but you dictate it on masterData.json instead on loginData.json?

Comment: This is now resolved. I made the test as a module which is called by MasterTest and MasterTest passed the parameter to the test module